# Identify mod operation in ARM firmware with IDA

Tags: ida, disassembly, arm

I have the firmware in which mod operation must be done. I want to find this part of instructions.

Assume the following logic exist in the firmware:

```
res = var % 17
```

I have tried to make search by `% 0x11` using IDA pseudocode and python but it does not find anything. Also I have tried to use gcc to dissemble this mod operation written in C but without any success.

Architecture: armv7-m

CPU: cortex-m4

Comment: I can't say for certain but one thing to look for would be [division by multiplication](https://saml98.github.io/jekyll/update/2020/02/21/weird-division.html) which could be involved in a modulo calculation. In short, look for a multiplication by a weird/large constant then a right shift by floor(log2(17)) = 4.

Answer (score 2):

An option in these cases is to compile a relevant code snippet with appropriate architecture options and see what assembly is generated.

For example, take this code.

```
long mod17( long x )
{
    return x % 17;
}
```

Compiling it with `gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -O2`, gives -

```
mod17(long):
        ldr     r3, .L3
        smull   r3, r2, r3, r0
        asrs    r3, r0, #31
        rsb     r3, r3, r2, asr #3
        add     r3, r3, r3, lsl #4
        subs    r0, r0, r3
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   2021161081    // 0x78787879
```

The output assembly gives some clues that you could look for in your firmware -

- the 'magic' constant `0x78787879`
- a multiplication instruction closely followed by 3 instructions containing shifts

Tests of similar code using `int` instead of `long` results in the same magic constant.

However, using unsigned integers results in a different magic constant - `0xF0F0F0F1` and just 1 shift instruction so you might want to look for these too.

(Compulsory [godbolt link.](https://godbolt.org/z/r8hEWYoWv))

Comment: As I wrote in my question I tried to do exactly what you have done but I am unable to find any magic constants or similar sequence of commands.